# I want my child method to not be executed if the outside method will fail (using javax @TransactionAttribute)

Tags: java, transactions, ejb

I have a method Meth1 witch will call a Meth2 from another class.
I want the Meth2 NOT to be executed if the Meth1 fails.

Both of them have REQUIRED attribute.
With this code, if the Meth1 fails while persisting (after Meth2 was executed succesfully), the Meth2 changes will remain.

I want all the code to be executed as a whole transaction, all or nothing.

Ex.:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
void meth1(){
    // ...some code
    otherClass.meth2();
    // ... some persistance that may fail
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
void meth2(){
    // some persistance
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What application server do you use?

Comment: I use JBoss server with a Seam framework. Your question made me find out that for Seam is better to use that annotation: @Transactional(TransactionPropagationType.REQUIRED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case both methods will be executed in the same transaction.

EJB specification 3.0 tells about REQUIRED:

> The container must invoke an enterprise bean method whose transaction
> attribute is set to the REQUIRED value with a valid transaction
> context.
>
> If a client invokes the enterprise bean’s method while the
> client is associated with a transaction context, the container invokes
> the enterprise bean’s method in the client’s transaction context.
>
> If
> the client invokes the enterprise bean’s method while the client is
> not associated with a transaction context, the container automatically
> starts a new transaction before delegating a method call to the
> enterprise bean business method. The container automatically enlists
> all the resource managers accessed by the business method with the
> transaction. If the business method invokes other enterprise beans,
> the container passes the transaction context with the invocation. The
> container attempts to commit the transaction when the business method
> has completed. The container performs the commit protocol before the
> method result is sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I realised a transaction can roll back only persistance actions. The change that remained is not a persistance one.